# How to enter percentage in a hot rhandsontable table rather digits?

Tags: r, rhandsontable

When editing a hot cell with a percentage format (`format = "0%"`), the value which appears (in "edition" mode) is switched back to a raw figure e.g. "-13.18%" in "edition mod" will look like 0.1318. This is a different behavior than most of the Excel-like spreadsheets (where when one edit a cell percentage one give a percentage) and therefore can be confusing for some users.

Is there a way to set up the same Excel behavior in a cell (or column or row) of a hot element?

Below an example:

```
data.frame(pct = rnorm(10)) %>%
  hot_col("pct", format = "0%")
```

Whether directly writing "15" in the first cell (value "-13.18%") or double-clicking it and then writing "15", result is 1500% (e.g. edited value is understood by the hot table as "raw" and not directly as a percentage value) where one would want 15%.

Comment: Don't add `format = '0%'` ? Using `rhandsontable(data.frame(pct = rnorm(10)))` gives the same number as shown in the table

Comment: Well, I want of course percentage in my table.